# Implementing fa unction that adds and sorts data in a singly linked list (addsort)?

Tags: c++, list, sorting, linked-list

I'm very new to C++ so it's a bit hard to understand the syntax sometimes. Anyways, I'm supposed to implement a function that adds and sorts the data given into a linked list. For example if I pass 2 into the list [1,4,5] then I should get [1,2,4,5]

Here is what I have written so far, and no it does not work, I keep getting "blah blah not declared in this scope"

```
void addSorted(Data * ){
  temp = 0;
  if (head == NULL) {
      head = new LinkNode(newData);
  }
  else {
      LinkNode * current = head;
      while (current->next != NULL) {
              current = current->next;
          }
      if(current->data > current->next->data){
          temp = current->data;
          current->data = current->next->data;
          current->next->data = temp;
      }
      current->next = new LinkNode(newData);
  }
}
```

Someone please help me, I'm using the struct LinkNode I think which is already given, in addition to a bunch of other functions like add, insert, remove, get, and size

I'm not looking to just get the answer, I need to know why what I have isn't working.

Comment: Please tell what the exactly error message is, otherwise it's hard to help you. `Data *` looks a bit strange, but I don't know if that is the problem.

Comment: That 'blahblah' is, believe it or not, significant. Please include the full error message and mark the line it happens on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that you have really put your effort in it..I am posting the whole function for inserting data into list in sorted order which I had written long time back

`void addData(node * head, int data){

        if(head == NULL) {  // First node

                node * temp = new node;
                temp -> data = data;
                temp -> next = NULL;
                head = temp;
                root = head;
        }else{

                node * prev = NULL;

                while(head -> next != NULL){  // Sorted Addition Logic is HERE

                        if(data >= head -> data){
                                prev = head;
                                head = head -> next;
                                continue;
                        }else{

                                node * temp = new node;
                                temp -> data = data; 
                                temp -> next = head;
                                if(prev != NULL)
                                   prev -> next = temp;
                                else
                                   head = temp;
                                break;
                        }
                }

                if(head -> next == NULL){

                        node * temp = new node;
                        temp -> data = data;
                        head -> next = temp;
                        temp -> next = NULL;
                }

        }
}`

Seeing your code, it seems that your logic itself is wrong...you are always ending on the last node (while loop) and in the next if statment you are trying to compare the data of the next node which is not present

Comment: okay thanks, i'm trying to just comprehend what you did there, srrry i'm a bit slow (and new), what does the "root" mean when you set it equal head (under the first "if")? Also, i'm sure how "continue" and "break" really work here? Im guessing "break" just like stop? But wat about continue?

Comment: First of all you really need a good book for C/C++ programming :). Dont worry about the first if "if(head == NULL)". That portion will be executed only for the first node.For the rest of the nodes it will go to the "else" portion.

Comment: "continue" means dont execute the remaining statements  after continue and start again from the loop(while in this case). "Break" means come out of loop and thus doesnt come into the loop again(while in this case)

Comment: As you are new to SO i will have to tell you that if you find any answer correct, then you have to accept that answer by clicking the "tick" below the VOte :). Else you wont find much helpers