# Sort after inserting an item into a Linked List?

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I have a C++ Program to insert Nodes to a linked list. The Nodes consist of a string that we'll call *data*, and a pointer to the next node that we'll call *next*. Also, the head node will be defined as *head*.

I'm not sure what's more efficient - 
 1. Inserting a bunch of strings to my list then sorting it afterward
 2. Or sorting the list as I insert.

I think it's the latter, and I am wondering how I will go about implementing something like that.

I want to know the simplest way to implement such a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had answered a similar question (99 % similar :) )  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540554/help-with-implementing-funtion-that-adds-and-sorts-data-in-a-singly-linked-list/7540588#7540588)

Now its for integer i guess, for string you can compare using `std::string compare` function or `strcmp` provided by C library

As per my  opinion and seeing other answers it would be better for your application (if it needs sorted linked list ) to sort the data as you insert .

Comment: I couldn't get your method to work. There's a line where you just have temp -> data; Is this supposed to be temp->data=data;? Either way, I couldn't get it to work properly. I'll try to figure out what I did wrong and come back here with results. Thanks :D

Comment: @chickeneaterguy : It must be some problem with the html tags. Even after 1 year I am having problem writing ">" in html :)

Comment: Thanks. I used a different approach, but yours was the most helpful.

Answer (score 4):

first solution: insert k elements unsorted, just insert them to the start, it is O(1) each. and one sort: `O(nlogn)` after these k elements. you get [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) time of `O(nlogn+k)/k  = O(n(logn/k))`.

second solution: inserting an element to a list is in sorted order is `O(n)`, since you need to find the place in the list. for k insertions, it will be `O(n*k)`, and amortized of `O(n*k/k) = O(n)`.

So the first solution is better for `logn < k`, and the second for `logn > k`

For better efficiency, you will probably want a sorted data structure that access elements in O(logn) such as a [skip-list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) [which is basically a variation of linked list with additional information for easier accessing] or an [avl tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)

Comment: Sorry, don't get how a sort on a linked list can be `O(n log n)` ?

Comment: @TonyTheLion: transform it to array [`O(n)`] sort [`O(nlogn)`] create a list from this array [`O(n)`]

Comment: You can also use quicksort directly on a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't actually make a difference how you do it, when you sort while inserting, you'll have O(n) on the insert, cause you might have to traverse the entire list before you find the right spot to insert.

However when you sort after adding all items to the list, you'll also have at least O(n) to move items around the list.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use what C++ already offers - `std::list` and `std::list::sort`:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Node {
public:
    Node(const std::string& data) : Data(data) {
    }
    std::string Data;
};

bool NodeLess(const Node& n1, const Node& n2) {
    return n1.Data < n2.Data;
}

void main() {

    std::list<Node> l;
    l.push_back(Node("d"));
    l.push_back(Node("c"));
    l.push_back(Node("a"));
    l.push_back(Node("b"));

    l.sort(NodeLess);

    for (auto i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << i->Data.c_str() << " ";

}
```

If you can get away with it (memory-wise), you could also use `std::vector` to pre-sort the items (through `std::sort`) before inserting them into linked list, which could be somewhat faster.

You could also use `std::map` (or even `std::set`) instead of list - it will "auto-sort" your items as you insert them.

If you still want to use your own list, you could implement `begin` and `end` in it, and use `std::stable_sort`. Note that `std::stable_sort` expects bidirectional iterators, (unlike `std::sort` which expects random-access iterators). To implement bidirectional iterators in your list, you'll need to make it doubly-linked, not just singly-linked.

If you want to implement the sort itself, it is possible to implement both [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort) on linked lists.

Comment: If you are going to use `std::list` then you should probably consider using the `list::sort` member function. Of course, profile to see which is better in your application.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I completely forgot about `std::list::sort`, thanks for reminding me! Edited the answer accordingly.